# Visual Studio Code Error: BOARD is not being defined on the CMake command-line in the environment or by the app

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cmake, nrf52

I am working on a project in VS Code with an nRF52dk and the nRF52805 BLE soc. I changed from segger studios to VS Code but now I get this error: *BOARD is not being defined on the CMake command-line in the environment or by the app*

Under the nRF connect app and Application I did configure my board *nrf52dk_nrf52805* and my device is connected too.
I don't have any experience with CMake files. is there something I might need to change in there or rebuild? I already tried deleting the build folders and doing a pristine build

Comment: In your project settings for Segger Studios there is very likely a "project settings" where environment variables and preprocessor directives are set. Probably under something like "language" or "C++ settings" - wherever you'd also set include directories or linked libraries. You should have a BOARD preprocessor directive explicitly set somewhere in there. Let us know when you find it. NOTE: I have never touched Segger Studios - this is based on my experience with other microcontroller IDEs.

Comment: You could (rather, *should*) also look at the debug information around that error. Does it point to a line in your CMake files? Does it point to a line in your source code? In the library's source code?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following in your nRF Connect terminal, to default to a certain board within that workspace.
`west config build.board <your_board>`
That's the easiest way if your only using one board for any of your projects, else there is a way to include it as an extra CMake argument in the build configuration. I think it would be something like
-DBOARD="c:/path/to/your/board"